# Geckofx closing and reopening in c#

Tags: c#, geckofx

What is needed : I need it to close and reopen the browser, I've tried a couple of things. Winform, c#.

What i've tried :

```
            using (Viewer = new GeckoWebBrowser())
            {
                Viewer.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                Viewer.Size = new Size(217, 257);
                Viewer.Location = new Point(0, 90);
                Viewer.Enabled = true;
                Viewer.Visible = true;
                Xpcom.Initialize("xulrunner");
                GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = false;
                GeckoPreferences.User["security.enable_ssl2"] = true;
                GeckoPreferences.User["security.default_personal_cert"] = "Ask Never";
                GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_entering_weak"] = true;
                GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_viewing_mixed"] = true;
                GeckoPreferences.User["dom.disable_open_during_load"] = true;
                GeckoPreferences.User["dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows"] = true;
                GeckoPreferences.User["dom.popup_maximum"] = 0;
                GeckoPreferences.User["dom.max_script_run_time"] = 0;
                GeckoPreferences.User["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
                Viewer.BringToFront();
                Viewer.Navigate("http://google.com");
                Viewer.Dispose();
            }
```

What is the problem?

It isn't showing up on the winform window.

Also i tried it with a windows control in the winform and using Viewer.Dispose(); destroyed the control completely and i wasn't able to access it any more.

Comment: Hello,
Where do you specify the parent of the browser? And what is the purpose of closing and showing the browser? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: IT is suppost to close the browser that way if it gets stuck on a captcha or something then reopen a new browser.